# Findout out user information in the Google APIs Console

Tags: google-oauth

When viewing your Google APIs console and selecting the Reports section under Usage you can see which APIs are being called, what region, how many users, etc.

But, I can't seem to find any way to list the users that are actually using the APIs. You can go to Reports>usage>users and hover over the graphs to see the number of requests for each user, but that's it.. no user information is associated with them.

How would I find out what the user ids are and how many requests they are making (and hopefully the specific request/API being used).

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in the Developer Console, for privacy reasons.

If you wish to find out which users are accessing your application, you need to integrate your application with OAuth2 and request that users explicitly grant your application authorization to identify them, by specifying that users authorize a scope such as 'email', 'profile', or 'openid'. Then you should be able to receive a token that discloses the Google user identifier to your information.